# PostgreSQL SQL position management

Tags: postgresql

How can I refer to a row in a table just by knowing its position in the table. For example, I have a table with 10 records, and I want the record that is in position 5, just as if it were an array management in programming.

Comment: This is a https://dba.stackexchange.com/ question

Comment: Based on the comment in an Answer, this is an XY Problem. Instead of asking how to implement your solution, please ask how to solve the root problem.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a great idea.

You are better off creating an id column if you want a specific row. Then using that for the select. You can also create an index on it to speed up queries.

You can do this with a column with type serial, which is an auto-incrementing type:

```
alter table TABLE_NAME
add column uid serial;
```

But if you really wanted to select the fifth row, you can use the row_number window function and a sub-query:

```
select * from
(
select row_number() over () as rn, * from TABLE_NAME
) sq
where rn = 5
```

It's a window query so it uses the *over* part to sort the table before applying the row number, by passing it nothing it uses the order as is. But this order may change.

Comment: Thank you very much. I already tried with that function but as I try to apply it in a context with thousands of records, Postgres informs me of a memory exhaustion error like this "SQL Error [53200]: ERROR: shared memory exhausted. Hint: max_locks_per_transaction may need to be incremented."

Comment: Did you increase max_locks_per_transaction? Why not create the id column then? Much easier. Also the query works fine, I can run it on a table with 40 million rows, it's just slow (takes 50 seconds) because it's calculating the row number for the whole table first then using it to select, but it is your setup that is having the problem.

Comment: I am creating a function to eliminate autocontacts in geometries. In the process I need to create a temporary table to compare positions in the nodes to verify autocontacts. So I can't create additional tables since I don't have permission in the base. In some internal process the memory is used up using row_number()